# Powershell to list files and have the user select one

Tags: powershell

I have a folder "D:\PROD\transfert" containing a list of files.

I want to write a Powershell script that will list the files and let the user chose one, the script will then perform actions on the selected file. Idealy I want the path of the selected file to be stored in a variable.

Here is the output wanted :

```
>Select a file :
[1] file1.zip
[2] file2.zip
[3] file3.zip
>
```

All i can do right now is listing the files with no number before :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\PROD\transfert | % { $_.FullName }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you absolutely need a console GUI, you could you can use `Out-GridView` to let a user choose, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\PROD\transfert | Out-GridView -Title 'Choose a file' -PassThru | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

***EDIT***
...and to store in a variable...

```
$filenames = @(Get-ChildItem C:\PROD\transfert | Out-GridView -Title 'Choose a file' -PassThru)
```

The `@()` wrapper ensures an array of filenames is always returned (even if one file or no files are chosen).

*(the `Passthru` relies on you having PowerShell 3 or greater)*

***EDIT 2***

The choice menu below will alter the display type, depending on whether in a console or GUI (e.g. ISE). I haven't tested over WinRM, but it shouldn't spawn a GUI when called via a normal PowerShell console.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\PROD\transfert -File
$fileChoices = @()

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
  $fileChoices += [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]("$($files[$i].Name) &$($i+1)")
}

$userChoice = $host.UI.PromptForChoice('Select File', 'Choose a file', $fileChoices, 0) + 1

# do something more useful here...
Write-Host "you chose $($files[$userChoice].FullName)"
```

Be careful of how many of files are returned by the `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: Ya, this is one way if he dont want a GUI based thing. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer it's doing what i want. However this script might be used over WinRM will the Out-GridView work ?

Comment: See latest edit, @kyori. That should work over WinRM.

Comment: @TechSpud thanks a lot that's perfect. Can't test WinRM now but looking at the code it should indeed work.

Comment: I tried the Edit 2 method and got this error message:
Exception calling "PromptForChoice" with "4" argument(s): ""choices" should have at least one element." ...

Comment: @Francis - are you using Core? There a several overloads in Windows PowerShell and ISE, including one with 4 params. Run `$host.UI.PromptForChoice` to list them. Amend your code to remove params that aren't available.